# Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE expected 1, got 0

Tags: mysql

estoy intentando hacer un procedimiento almacenado en mi base de datos, para ello uso funciones que pues ya he comprobado, este es el código:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insertarVenta//
CREATE PROCEDURE insertarVenta(OUT cvv INT)
BEGIN
DECLARE fechaventa VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK;
END;
START TRANSACTION;      
    SET cvv = cvVentaNva(); 
    SET fechaventa = fechaActual();
    INSERT ventas(cvventa, fechav) VALUES (cvv, fechaventa);
COMMIT;
END//
```

Y el error es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mis funciones pues si están mandando valores correctos pero no se que pasa que me marca ese error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regularmente cuando utilizas un parámetro de salida en un procedimiento almacenado debes de declarar una variable del mismo tipo de dato para recibir ese valor desde el procedimiento al momento de que realizas la invocación.

Puedes revisar esta [liga](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/stored-procedures-parameters.aspx) en la sección de **The OUT parameter example** para que veas la sintaxis correcta para que puedas corregir el error

Basado en tu ejemplo
CALL insertarVenta(@cvv);
SELECT @cvv;
Saludos
Happy Code